# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of tensor product of identity and transpose of a rank-$1$ matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, mathematical-physics

Let $\psi^{A \tilde{A}}:=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ with $\left|\psi^{A \tilde{A}}\right\rangle=\sum_{x=1}^{|A|} \sqrt{p_{x}}|x\rangle|x\rangle \in A \otimes \tilde{A}$.

Now, I'm looking for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $\mathrm{id}^{A} \otimes \mathcal{T}\left(\psi^{A \tilde{A}}\right),$ where $\mathcal{T}$ is the transpose map.

ATTEMPT:

First I find out that the eigenvalues of $\psi^{A \tilde{A}}$ is one and $|A|$ zeros if $\sqrt{p_{x}}=\frac{1}{|A|}$. But I have no idea about this problem which $\sqrt{p_{x}}$ can be anything.
Totally I know that a rank-$1$ matrix has one none-zero eigenvalue (if you ask me why, I'll tell you :-|).

But the main part of my question is about the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $\mathrm{id}^{A} \otimes \mathcal{T}\left(\psi^{A \tilde{A}}\right),$. I think this is a tensor commutation matrix $|A|\otimes |A|$. Could you please help me?

I should mention that hilbert space $\tilde{A}$ is replica of $A$ and they are exactly the same. And $\mathrm{id}^{A}$ is the identity matrix in $A$

Comment: A rank-1 matrix *can* have but *doesn't have to* have a non-zero eigenvalue, right ?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it has to have one non-zero eigenvalue.

Comment: Consider the matrix of the transformation  of collapsing the space to one of the axes followed by a rotation not about this axis. There is no line that is retained, so there is no nonzero eigenvalues. However it has zero as an eigenvalue. I hope that is correct